# Stripe, how to retrieve payment history?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

For my react app, I am using the [Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) object to handle purchases in Stripe, and I am using a Customer object if the user is logged in. I tried using [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents), however it only gives me the total balance for each payment and not the actual items and their amounts that were purchased. I want to be able to retrieve the line_items a customer purchased in each payment (they're not Product objects if that helps).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the Session object, [which does contain those](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items).

Comment: It seems to require the ID for each session. Is there any way to retrieve all the sessions associated with the id of a Customer object, like with Payment Intents?

Comment: In this case, just list (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) all of them, and select the ones for the Customer object - and then figure out how to store this yourself going forward.